# Starting Exasol docker-db without privileges in Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: docker, integration-testing, bitbucket-pipelines, testcontainers, exasol

I'm trying to run an integration test using testcontainers in my Bitbucket Pipeline. For each test I need to start up a fresh [Exasol image](https://github.com/exasol/docker-db). This, however, needs to be started in priviledged mode

> for permissions management, UDF support and environment configuration and validation

, which in turn is not allowed by bitbucket.

Is there a way of starting up the Exasol image without privileged mode? Or has someone an idea for a different solution so I'll be able to run my integration tests?

Comment: Just for the record: no, it is not possible. You absolutely need the privileged mode in order to start Exasol.